# Chrome.webrequest.onBeforeRequest calling itself multiple times

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension using JavaScript API in which I'm trying to redirect the URL when its matches with webrequest URLs pattern

[how chrome.webrequest.onebforerequest calling itsself multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcsnG.png)

**backgorund.js**

```js
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
            function(details) {
                var host="https://api.answerme.com/2.2/questions/345797";
                var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
                x.open('GET',host,false);

                x.onload = function() {
                // this function gives me URL and store into "redirectAnswerUrl" global variable (working fine)
                setRedirectedToAnswer(x.responseText);
                };      
                x.send();
         //this working fine output:-www.answerme.com/quetion/78784#45545
         alert("redirectAnswerUrl"+redirectAnswerUrl);
                if(redirectAnswerUrl!=""){
                  //but this redirectAnswerUrl has same pattern of default urls that is above output and manifest url  
                 return {redirectUrl: redirectAnswerUrl}
                }

            },
            {
                 //setting url which we gonna match during first load 
                 urls: [
                    "*://answerme.com/questions/*",
                    "*://www.answerme.com/questions/*"
                 ]
            },
            ["blocking"]
        );
```

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "name": "Demo",
    "description": "Demo",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "logo.png",
        "default_popup": "window.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab", "tabs", "webRequest",
        "*://answerme.com/questions/*",
        "*://www.answerme.com/questions/*"
        "webRequestBlocking", "storage"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "logo.png",
        "128": "logo.png"
    }
}
```

**Problem** :Same url pattern that is being checked on webrequest that is API ouput url has "**www.answerme.com/quetion**/78878#787878" and webrequest url has "**www.answerme.com/quetion**/searchquery"

In this case, when we get `www.answerme.com/questions/searchquery` the page will be redirected to the `http://www.answerme.com/questions/7847859#748555`, but the problem is: the pattern I use to check the URL has `*` to indicate the URL can start with any protocol and its first attributes start with `quetions`. This matches the redirect URL, `http://www.answerme.com/questions/7847859#7848488`, so this becomes deadlocked (repeatedly redirected). I'm getting same URL pattern request(`redirect url= www.asswerme.com/quetion/7878#7878  and webrequest url on manifest file has www.asswerme.com/quetion/*`) again again, so I decided to check the URL doesn't end with a number (webrequest manifest), so that I can easily redirect them to `http://www.answerme.com/questions/7847859#14524` without any ambiguity.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify. Please specify *exactly* the URLs which you are attempting to redirect. For instance, do you want to redirect **all** `*://*.example.com/add/*` URLs except `http://www.example.com/add/7847859` to `http://www.example.com/add/7847859`? If so, then just test the URL to see if it contains that: `if (details.url.indexOf('http://www.example.com/add/7847859') !== 0) { return { redirectUrl: 'http://www.example.com/add/7847859' };}`

Comment: yes.. i want url that end with number#number 121454#25544 because whenever i get response from api i get this url in this format example.com/add/4545454#44555 so i want extactly same pattern

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Please specify **exactly** what you want to redirect and what you don't want to redirect (if anything other than your redirect URL). Give multiple examples. Frankly, the fact that you are not explicitly defining this is the basis of the problem that you are having. It's also unclear if you are experiencing a problem which some other redirect extensions have, which is that the site will redirect the redirect to yet another matching page, thus causing a loop with multiple stages.

Comment: Further, you should explicitly make a choice if you are wanting to redirect *every* request to these matching URLs, or just those which are the result of page navigation to those specific pages (usually less likely to cause problems).

Comment: i have updated the question and provides definition also provide me the solution or logic i was thinking to match url end up with the 7877#7878 because that is the API url response that i wanted to redirect

Comment: You've significantly changed the question. Please provide code for `setRedirectedToAnswer()`. Presumably it sets `redirectAnswerUrl`. Why are you not just comparing the `details.url` to `redirectAnswerUrl` and not redirecting when that's the URL. I provided code in my first comment which should look for the redirected URL and not redirect if that begins the `details.url`.

Comment: i cant check both urls is different but problem is webrequest url pattern because any url has pattern with this webrequest url so it will go inside chrome.webrequest and i dont want that because its create deadlock its calling itself again again

Comment: Why can't you check `details.url !== redirectAnswerUrl`? Or `details.url.indexOf(redirectAnswerUrl) !== 0`, or some similar comparison?

Comment: see i have updated with image you would see how things are happen ...no i cant because everytime it will get inside chrome.werequest that i dont want because redirecturl is diffrent and detailsurl is diffrent problme is url pattern we have to check the url pattern

Comment: Then you save the URL to which you redirected into another variable and check against that. You make the check prior to changing the `redirectAnswerUrl` so you do nothing if it's the URL to which you redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution define `redirectAnswerUrl="";` and check with condition if `redirectAnswerUrl==""` go inside else redirect

```
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
                function(details) {
                if(redirectAnswerUrl==""){
                    var host="https://api.answerme.com/2.2/questions/345797";
                    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    x.open('GET',host,false);

                    x.onload = function() {
                    // this function gives me URL and store into "redirectAnswerUrl" global variable (working fine)
                    setRedirectedToAnswer(x.responseText);
                    };      
                    x.send();
             //this working fine output:-www.answerme.com/quetion/78784#45545
             alert("redirectAnswerUrl"+redirectAnswerUrl);
                    if(redirectAnswerUrl!=""){
                      //but this redirectAnswerUrl has same pattern of default urls that is above output and manifest url  
                     return {redirectUrl: redirectAnswerUrl}
                    }else{
                  return {redirectUrl: details.url}
}

                },
                {
                     //setting url which we gonna match during first load 
                     urls: [
                        "*://answerme.com/questions/*",
                        "*://www.answerme.com/questions/*"
                     ]
                },
                ["blocking"]
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegExp` to check if `details.url` ends with only digit characters

```
if (!/^\d+$/.test(details.url.split("/").pop())) {
  // `details.url` does not end with only digits, do other stuff
} else {
  return {redirectUrl: "http://www.example.com/add/7847859"}
}
```

Comment: but urls [ "*://example.com/add/*"] says that if its match with any url which start with add it will redirect..as per this solution again url will be in the loop because "http://www.example.com/add/7847859" has add ...so i want regular expression of urls for this [ "*://example.com/add/*"]  how can we do it ?

Comment: @UmeshShende _"says that if its match with any url which start with add it will redirect."_ Does not the redirect actually occur at `return {redirectUrl: "http://www.example.com/add/7847859"}` ?

Comment: have updated the quetions i tried with ..but i i think its does not detect end with number

Comment: What does `console.log(details.url)` log?

Comment: its getting inside if block even url has end with number like www.exmple.com/add/784681#12452658

Comment: @UmeshShende _"www.exmple.com/add/784681#12452658"_ is a different URL pattern from the URL described at original Question _"http://www.example.com/add/7847859"_ Which URL are you trying to match?

Comment: step one :first  match url( exmaple.com/add/4575445/searchresult)   then proccess and proccess will give new redirect url is "https://www.exmple.com/add/145125#122451" so i wanted to redirect this url

Comment: Remove `!` from beginning of expression within `if` condition to match URL which only contains digits `/^\d+$/.test("exmaple.com/add/4575445".split("/").pop()) // true`, `/^\d+$/.test("https://www.exmple.com/add/145125#122451".split("/").pop()) // false`

Comment: can it be possible to check last parameter should be number#number because im getting https://exmple.com/add/142515#12251252 and even probem has not solved removing ` ! ` this

Comment: @UmeshShende What do you mean? You are redirecting to "exmple.com/add/142515#12251252" only if URL is "exmple.com/add/142515", yes? You can check the `.hash` of the URL to determing if the hash is all numbers 
`URL("https://exmple.com/add/142515#12251252").hash && /^\d+$/.test(new URL("https://exmple.com/add/142515#12251252").hash.slice(1))`

Comment: Reason is on load webrequest will get URL  process URL and fetch id from it ,id will be process in api call and api gives us URL which I wanted to redirect that is example.com/add/223333#333333

Comment: @UmeshShende Not gathering what the issue is?

Comment: Simple i want to redirect the URL which API gives me ..im calling api on load page so when url generate from api simply i want that url to be redirected so problem in redirecting because default url and API callback URL is same pattern so result in ambiguity and call same onload function multiple times

Comment: "example.com/add/223333#333333" and "example.com/add/223333" are not the same pattern, use the logic of `if..else` conditions

Comment: see url pattern of chrome.webrequest in manifest and backgorund js also..*://example.com/add/* it means it will accept any url which match this thats the real problem

Comment: Yes, though you can use logic within callback function. _"//im getting inside even url has end up with number exmple.com/add/4548#458"_ The code at updated Question does not remove `!` operator as described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864162/how-to-match-urls-which-will-end-with-number-in-chrome-webrequest-api/46864254?noredirect=1#comment80676805_46864254 `/^\d+$/.test("exmple.com/add/4548#458".split("/").pop())` returns `false`

Comment: what will be the solution is there any pattern for matches url in chrome.webrequest like i want ..

Comment: Not according to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns, unless you can locate such a pattern at the documentation

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: You can try using the `if..else` statements with correct logic

Comment: ok Thank you @quest271314...if I get  solution I definitely update.